# Return value of print statement in Python

Tags: python, printing, return

In one book I found that`print(print("any text"))` returns the size of text inside the function. i.e. 8 Here

But in another book I found out that it returns `None`.

So which answer is true?
Or whether the 2nd answer is just an updated answer...?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try in the console?

Comment: Are you sure the first book had `print(print(` and not `print(output.write(`?

Comment: Whenever you have confusion about return values or parameters, 1) check the official documentation 2) if it is not clear there, try out the same by writing a program 3) send a patch to Python to fix the documentation

Comment: *print statement in Python*  ---> Nope, you're using Python 3, so `print()` is a function, not a statement. If you run your code in Python 2 it'll raise `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: In Python 2.x, `print` is a *statement* and doesn't return a value.  If you try `print(print("x"))` in 2.6 it causes a syntax error.  In 3.x, print is a function and as such *can* have a return value, which it doesn't.... so yes in 3.x the `print()` **function** returns `None`.  You must be mistaken about the first part of this question or your book is incorrect.

Comment: FWIW, the C `printf` function _does_ return the number of characters written (or a negative value if an error occurred). So maybe the author of that book was confusing Python with C...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function doesn't return anything (so it's `None`). When you're printing the output of a function which returns `None`, sure the output is `None`. So the 2nd book is correct.

```
>>> print(print())

None
```

If you want get the length of a string, you should use [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) function:

```
>>> print(len("any text"))
8
```

Answer (score 2):

In python return value of print is None. Maybe you are confusing it with C, where the "printf" function returns the number of characters printed.

Answer (score 0):

At first innner print function is executed and the string in inner print function i.e, "any text" is printed.
After that it prints none

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).